# Is there any way to change App source on Android?

Tags: oneplus-3, device-migration, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I migrated from Oneplus 3(Chinese android phone) to Galaxy Note 8 via Cloneit, since Samsung's stock migration tool didn't support Oneplus 3.

However, apps migrated(or preferably, cloned) on my new phone are recognized as 'app installed from unknown source' instead of 'installed from Google Play'.

It seems that Cloneit, the migration tool brought all apk files via connection and that's making all apps recognized as unknown source.

*
So, I want to change their source property from unknown to installed from Google Play. 
*

My speculation is pretty pessimistic since it sounds like it's related to some security issues but I'm hoping some Superuser has an answer for this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible if you have root.

Comment: @iBug Long live TiBu.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman No need for TiBu. Just a matter of a shell command.

Comment: @iBug For you, me and a bunch of others, it's just a shell command. For many casual users, it's a (s)hell command.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Your comment is accepted ✔. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is as simple as a few (s)hell commands. Requires root and BusyBox.

Open a terminal or an `adb shell` and type

```
su
sed -i 's/installer="[A-Za-z0-9._-]*"/installer="com.android.vending"/g' /data/system/packages.xml
```

If the command prompt tells you `sed: not found`, install BusyBox correctly and prepend `busybox` before `sed`.

---

Be aware that this is a highly dangerous action. It is **strongly** recommended that you backup the file before attempting to modify it. Also in some cases the file permission may get messed up, fix it by

```
chmod 0660 /data/system/packages.list
chown 1000.1000 /data/system/packages.list
```

Comment: Wait, with this you can trick the OS into treating arbitrary apps as coming from Play? What about within Play itself - does it then list and update such apps?

Comment: Upvoted because I enjoy messing around with `packages.xml`.

Comment: @AndyYan Play updates any app you're eligible for - including those explicitly marked as "not installed by Play" - as long as you own it with your Google Account.

Comment: @AndyYan Play seems not to have a list of "installed by me" itself.

Comment: Well that "owned" list is pretty much what I was thinking of... How silly I was to have forgotten about that. Thanks and +1 for the explanation.

Comment: I don't what the problem was, but after doing this and rebooting, I faced bootloop, which I finally  found how to resolve by `chmod 777 /data/system/packages.xml` from TWRP's Terminal (I noticed the `FileNotFoundException` in logcat during boot for packages.xml). It might sound weird, but yes, it happened to me. Also, on a safer side, it'd be better to backup `packages.xml` first, incase the user typed even a single letter wrong leading to World War III.

Comment: @GokulNC Good I'll add the notice.

Comment: Thanks guys. I chose to migrate with Cloneit and expected no further Play store updates but when I restarted my device all apps were soundly marked as 'Installed by me' and future updates were eligible. I checked the apps from the setting and they are still marked as 'installed from package' rathet than 'installed from Play store' but anyhow it works.

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with shell commands and I'm very far from Android Dev. So  I'm happy I didn't have to root or anything. Plus, Samsung's Galaxy has Knox in it which leaves a permanent mark if I ever root my device and it will no longer be eligible for bankings and credit payment.